# Shadow glitch using compton; "glass" rectangle showing around Nautilus' windows

Tags: xubuntu, nautilus, xfce, compton

I'm using compton on my xubuntu 16.10 beacause this way my system is tearing free. When i use Thunar the windows shadows are OK, but if i use Nautilus (which i prefer) the windows' shadows appear glitched like in the image.

[image: This is the glitch]

This happens even if I disable shadow completely from the compton.conf.

Here's my compton.conf:

```
# Compton Configuration, courtesy of Xubuntu Developers
# Please note that Compton is not supported by Xubuntu and may not work
# correctly for you. This file is provided as a set of sane defaults and is in
# no way endorsed by the Xubuntu team.
#
# About Compton: https://github.com/chjj/compton
# Heavily based on: http://bit.ly/1l5OrzL
# Sample settings: https://github.com/chjj/compton/blob/master/compton.sample.conf

# --- Backend (OpenGL used by default)
# Related Links
# https://github.com/chjj/compton/wiki/perf-guide
# https://github.com/chjj/compton/wiki/vsync-guide

backend = "glx";
paint-on-overlay = true;
glx-no-stencil = true;
glx-no-rebind-pixmap = true;
unredir-if-possible = true;
vsync = "opengl-swc"; 


# --- Shadows (Disable with shadow = false;)
# The shadow exclude options are helpful if you have shadows enabled.
# Due to the way compton draws its shadows, certain applications (Such as
# shaped windows, custom popups, non-standard toolkits) will have visual glitches.

shadow = true;              # Enabled client-side shadows on windows.
no-dock-shadow = true;      # Avoid drawing shadows on dock/panel windows.
no-dnd-shadow = true;       # Don't draw shadows on DND windows.
clear-shadow = true;        # Zero the part of the shadow's mask behind the window (experimental).
shadow-radius = 10;         # The blur radius for shadows. (default 10)
shadow-offset-x = -15;      # The left offset for shadows. (default -15)
shadow-offset-y = -12;      # The top offset for shadows. (default -12)
shadow-opacity = 0.4;
shadow-exclude = [
 "! name~=''",              # "Unknown" windows, including xfwm4 alt-tab
 "n:e:Notification",
 "n:e:Plank",
 "n:e:Docky",
 "g:e:Synapse",
 "g:e:Kupfer",
 "g:e:Conky",
 "n:w:*Firefox*",
 "n:w:*Chrome*",
 "n:w:*Chromium*",
 "class_g ?= 'Notify-osd'",
 "class_g ?= 'Cairo-dock'",
 "class_g ?= 'Xfce4-notifyd'",
 "class_g ?= 'Xfce4-power-manager'",
 "class_g ?= 'Xfwm4'",      # For the "new" xfwm4 alt-tab
 "_GTK_FRAME_EXTENTS@:c",   # GTK+ 3 CSD windows https://github.com/chjj/compton/issues/189
 "class_g ?= 'Nautilus'",
 "WM_CLASS@:s *?= 'Nautilus'"
];


# --- Fading (Disable with fading = false;)

fading = true;              # Fade windows during opacity changes.
fade-delta = 5;             # The time between steps in a fade in milliseconds. (default 5).
fade-in-step = 0.03;        # Opacity change between steps while fading in. (default 0.03).
fade-out-step = 0.03;       # Opacity change between steps while fading out. (default 0.03).


# --- Additional Settings
detect-client-opacity = true;


# --- Window type settings
wintypes:
{
  tooltip = { fade = true; shadow = false; opacity = 0.9; focus = true; };
};
```

To note that i'm using Adapta-nokto as gtk theme.
Any ideas? Thank you

UPDATE: so executing `compton --shadow-exclude '_NET_WM_OPAQUE_REGION@:c'`
solve the problem but i get `Another composite manager is already running`

Also adding `'_NET_WM_OPAQUE_REGION@:c'` to the shadow exclude section of compton.conf doesn't work after reastart

Comment: How exactly are you defining "glitched"?  Related: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2144468 & http://askubuntu.com/questions/696786/compton-incorrect-shadow-display-favourite-settings

Comment: Take a look at the image i posted, there is a transparent rectangle around the window. Also i tried adding nautilus to shadow exclusions as you can see from the config but with no result.

Comment: I saw the image you posted. What I'm not clear on is how this differs from what you expected. Hence the request for definition.

Comment: executing 'compton --shadow-exclude '_NET_WM_OPAQUE_REGION@:c'' works. But I get  'Another composite manager is already running'

Answer (score 0):

If you disable this will remove the transparent box outside of certain windows
**clear-shadow = true;        # Zero the part of the shadow's mask behind the window (experimental).**
But it will add them a shadow in its place.

I tried the command you said plus clear-shadow=false it fixes that but now some windows do not have shadow at all